# Correct Syntax for Inline ES6 Modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Which one is correct syntax for inline modules

`<module>`

or

`<script type="module"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are valid, although I would argue `<module>` is slightly more correct, see explanation below:

The code inside `<script>` elements does not support module syntax, because the element’s synchronous nature is incompatible with the asynchronicity of modules. Instead, you need to use the new `<module>` element. It has several significant advantages over `<script>`. However script can used in its alternative form `<script type="module">`.

Comment: I have a question. Why code inside `<module>` has its own scope instead of global scope? For example: a variables inside `<module>` tag is not visible to any other `<module>` or `<script>` tags

Comment: It's kinda in the name, "module" implies that it would be scoped to the module, global scope was always a bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`<module>` is the proposed element for loading ES6 modules into HTML documents.

`<script type="module">` is a temporary work-around until:

- `<module>` gets properly standardised
- Browsers start to support `<module>`

[source](http://www.2ality.com/2013/11/es6-modules-browsers.html)

Comment: That source link is from 2013. There's nothing like that in the ES6 (final) standard.

Comment: @Amit: ES doesn't specify this at all. WHATWG is working on the loader.

Comment: @bergi - Can you share any relevant links (Pehaps inject into the answer instead of that "old" link?). Also, is that part of the proposed loader that replaces the old proposed "System.Import"?

Comment: @Amit: I'm not up-to-date, but these should get you started: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/any-news-about-the-module-element, https://whatwg.github.io/loader/

Comment: @Bergi the whatwg one is the one I referred to on my previous comment. Nothing about markup there. the other link (esdicuss) is interesting, but that too doesn't link to any draft/proposal or the likes... It is "only" 8 months old though, so that might still be alive.

Comment: @Amit: Ah, right. Not sure whether it's still alive either, the latest discussion I found related to it is https://github.com/whatwg/loader/issues/42